# Creating a kik chatbot

Tags: java, python, kik

I am trying to create a Kik bot with Python

I am famailiar with Python and REST. I have gone through the docs:

[Kik Docs](https://dev.kik.com/#/docs/messaging)

To begin, I need:

```
requests.post(
'https://api.kik.com/v1/config',
auth=('<username>', '<api_key>'),
headers={
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
},
data=json.dumps({
    'webhook': 'https://example.com/incoming', 
    'features': {
        'receiveReadReceipts': False, 
        'receiveIsTyping': False, 
        'manuallySendReadReceipts': False, 
        'receiveDeliveryReceipts': False
    }
})
)
```

But they do not tell us what "webhook," or any of this code really means?

how do I set up the config? **What do I put for** 'username'? My own username?

Comment: Before posting a question you should first search the web for a tutorial, e,g, [Build a Kik Chatbot with API.AI's One-click Integration - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lGp6ztjy3xQ).

Comment: @MikeJRamsey56, I saw that video before but I don't think you did. That has nothing to do with coding, its just a website promoting their service.

Comment: Advise still stands; find a tutorial.

Comment: @MikeJRamsey56, I've tried but can't find one? I even Emailed Kik to no avail

Comment: Keep looking.  You are not the first person to be in this position so innovation (i.e. applying something that has worked elsewhere to your situation) is preferable to creativity (i.e. invention out of whole cloth).  Have you looked [here](https://medium.com/@giuliano/how-to-build-a-pizza-ordering-kik-bot-with-stamplay-d132f3aafa2f#.iadtat5i5)?

Answer (score 1):

A webhook is the route on your local / production server that will receive the messages from Kik's platform

Answer (score 0):

API KEY: The key received from the dev.kik.com after setting up your bot.
USERNAME: Bots username
URL: URL made for the server.

Step 1: Download NPM
Step 2: Run "npm install" in CMD Prompt in the file your code is in (I use C:\Owners although pretty sure it can be anywhere)
Step 3: Download NGROK (Run "npm install ngrok -g" in command prompt)
Step 4: Run "ngrok http 8080" in CMD Prompt
Step 5: Open your index.js file (probably config/index.js)
Step 6: Input the api key, username, and link you got from the ngrok, which should look something like this.

```
Session Status                online
Version                       2.1.18
Region                        United States (us)
Web Interface                 http://127.0.0.1:4040
Forwarding                    http://*********.ngrok.io -> localhost:8080
Forwarding                    https://*********.ngrok.io -> localhost:8080

Connections                   ttl     opn     rt1     rt5     p50     p90
                              128     0       0.00    0.00    95.46   120.78
```

The *** are numbers that will be filled in with yours. So you would put for example

```
requests.post(
'https://api.kik.com/v1/config',
auth=('<botName>', '<1111-1111-1111-1111-1111>'),
    headers={
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
data=json.dumps({
    'webhook': 'http://111111111.ngrok.io', 
    'features': {
        'receiveReadReceipts': False, 
        'receiveIsTyping': False, 
        'manuallySendReadReceipts': False, 
        'receiveDeliveryReceipts': False
    }
})
)
```

After this, you should be fine as long as the computer is not shut off or command windows closed. If this does happen, run the ngrok http 8080 again and replace the link in the index.js to the updated link. Then again, there a ways such as setting a domain link as a server so you do not need to keep a server command window open, but I am yet to try this. I'll try and update if I ever try this :)

-Root